# How to retrieve values from my Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning how to perform CRUD operation using firebase. So far, there's no problem in inserting a data onto my database, but I have a problem trying to retrieve data from it, it keeps returning **null** even though there's an existing value in my database.

Here is an example of my database for reference:

```
https://exer3firebaseapp-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/
RvListModel
  asd-12-11
    -Ndj_usRDjM0CnBICFme
      tvName : "asd"
      tvNumber : "11"
      tvYear : "12"

  sdf-11-33
    -NdjbRXtl9YQK8j_cB7u
      tvName : "sdf"
      tvNumber : "33"
      tvYear : "11"
```

[image]

Then this is my code for retrieving the data:

```
//  GETTING ALL data from firebase
fun getValueFromDB() {
    val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            dataRetrievedFromDBLocal.clear()
            for (childSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                val uID = childSnapshot.key.toString()
                val tvName = childSnapshot.child(uID).child("tvName").value.toString()
                val tvYear = childSnapshot.child(uID).child("tvYear").value.toString()
                val tvNumber = childSnapshot.child(uID).child("tvNumber").value.toString()

                dataRetrievedFromDBLocal.add(
                    RvListModel(tvName, tvYear, tvNumber)
                )
                dataRetrievedFromDB.value = dataRetrievedFromDBLocal
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.i("MyTag", error.message)
        }
    }

    Dao.databaseReference.addValueEventListener(postListener)
}
```

Then this is my Dao class:

```
object Dao {

    //  firebase realtime database SINGLETON initialization using object class
    var databaseReference: DatabaseReference

    init {
        val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        databaseReference = db.getReference(RvListModel::class.simpleName!!)
    }

    fun add(rvListModel: RvListModel, childNodeID: String) = databaseReference.child(childNodeID).push().setValue(rvListModel)
}
```

I've tried to manually input all of the nodes by using using series of `.child()` starting from the root node until the very end of the tree but it still returns a `null` value.

Comment: What is `RvListModel::class.simpleName` in `db.getReference(RvListModel::class.simpleName!!)? Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded path? If so, can you show the code for that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for the response! So that function only returns the String name of my class, which is `RvListModel`, which will then be used as the name of my Root node as seen in my uploaded picture. I tried inputting the String name of my class for the `.getReference` function as an argument but it still produces the same error I'm getting. Btw my `RvListModel` class is a data class that only contains three string declarations, namely, `tvName`, `tvYear`, and `tvNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance you used `.push().setValue(...)` to build this structure, which is why you have two nested dynamic key levels in your data structure: `asd-12-11` vs `-Ndj...`.

Your code needs to have both of these nested dynamic levels, but only handles one of them. To fix this, add a nested loop:

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    dataRetrievedFromDBLocal.clear()
    for (childSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
        for (grandchildSnapshot in childSnapshot.children) {
            val uID = grandchildSnapshot.key.toString()
            val tvName = grandchildSnapshot.child(uID).child("tvName").value.toString()
            val tvYear = grandchildSnapshot.child(uID).child("tvYear").value.toString()
            val tvNumber = grandchildSnapshot.child(uID).child("tvNumber").value.toString()

            dataRetrievedFromDBLocal.add(
                RvListModel(tvName, tvYear, tvNumber)
            )
            dataRetrievedFromDB.value = dataRetrievedFromDBLocal
        }
    }
}
```

If this still doesn't work, it may help to step through the code in a debugger and check the value of each variable on each line. The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the `child(uID)` to prevent it from returning a null value. It still returns a null value if I include it (though I still don't know why I shouldn't included the jumbled letters node inside the `.child()` function). I placed two logs, the first log in the first loop and the second log inside the nested loop in order to check the results. Nevertheless, thank you for pinpointing a solution. It works now. 
My logs:`Inside the first loop - {-NdkVHmAIYh4Bz_2MylY={tvYear=11, tvName=test1, tvNumber=22}}`
`Inside the nested loop - {tvYear=11, tvName=test1, tvNumber=22}`

Comment: What value does your `uID` variable have?

Comment: My `uID` is always the the returned value of `.key.toString()`, which is the jumbled letters node of my tree, e.g., `-Ndj_usRDj...` and `NdjbRXt..`.

Comment: Hmm... in that case your original code actually looks fine. You say that "it keeps returning null". Can you clarify what you mean by that, as there's no `return` statement in the code you shared. It might help if you `Log.w` the value that you expected in your code, and share the updated code and output with us.

Comment: (1) Sure! I was actually referring to the `.value.toString()` when I always said "returning null" since that code is supposed to return a value coming from my firebase, but instead, it returns `null` in string format (since I used `.value.toString()`), that's when I thought that maybe the problem lies at the path of the nodes that I'm specifying using the `.child()`.

Comment: (2) Using my original code (the code I posted above), in order to check what value `childSnapshot` is returning, I tried to add `Log.i(TAG, childSnapshot.value.toString())` inside my for loop, and upon checking it, this is what it returns (`{-NdnfCkU6I8soLm_daM0={tvYear=11, tvName=test1, tvNumber=22}}`).

Comment: Can you update your question with the updated code and its output? That's a bit easier to read. Also, since it seems the problem isn't addressed, I recommend removing the checkmark from my answer to make that clear to both the system and other users here who might be able to help before I got to it..